# initialize cpu regs to zero in start of arm trusted firmware code

Tags: c, arm, firmware, cortex-a

I am building a ATF bl1 secure-boot, currently in simulation I have an issue that I suspect that is related to accessing uninitialized registers.

I'm trying to understand if there is a code that in startup initializes the processor registers and where it is located

[image: cortex a7 registers set]

Comment: "how to initialize core registers set at start" - that's rather simple, you write zero to register...

Comment: But why do you need to port Trusted Firmware ? The whole point of trusted firmware is to be run in 'trusted' level and 'Cortex-A7' as I'm aware does not have it

Comment: I am building a ATF bl1 secure-boot, currently in simulation I have an issue that I suspect that is related to accessing uninitialized registers.
I'm trying to understand if there is a code that in startup initializes the processor registers and where it is located

Comment: A world switch should restore all banked registers.  When a world starts, the values can be random.  This is a bug in the software in the world.  Before 2nd worlds start, the ATF doesn't need to set these values.  So for instance, Linux expects a boot loader to have set the registers.  If you boot Linux directly in the Normal world, you need to fulfil the requirements of a boot loader.  Structurally, your question seems to make no sense; the monitor mode switches all these registers on a world switch.  They have to be initialize twice, once for each world or the world doesn't depend on this.